# How do I convert strings of numbers, coming from a .txt file into an int array using stoi::("string")

Tags: visual-c++

I've been trying to take a .txt document with three number entries, read those entries as strings and convert those entries in ints, then put them into an int array, but had no success in doing so and i have no clue as to why. Note that the entries as well as some variable names are pre determined by the assignment, additionally we have to use the std::stoi("string") command, which i am not familiar with nor has any syntax been provided to us (which is especially strange since we are usually not allowed to stray to far from the lecture material)
What I excpected to happen is that the numbers from the .txt file were converted into an array, however what actually happened is that an "unhandled exception" (my apologies if that term does not make sanes we have to programm in our native language) occured and the string library opened itself, marking the error on line 107. The problematic line in my code seems to be "auftraegearray[i++] = std::stoi(MengeanAuftraegen);"

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream Auftraege;
    Auftraege.open("Auftraege37.txt", std::ios::out);
    Auftraege << "10" << std::endl;
    Auftraege << "1" << std::endl;
    Auftraege << "20" << std::endl;
    Auftraege.close();

    int i = 0;
    int auftraegearray[4];
    std::string MengeanAuftraegen;
    Auftraege.open("Auftraege37.txt", std::ios::in);
    while (!Auftraege.eof())
    {
        getline(Auftraege, MengeanAuftraegen);
        std::cout << MengeanAuftraegen << std::endl;
        auftraegearray[i++] = std::stoi(MengeanAuftraegen);



    }

    Auftraege.close();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead? In what way does the code shown fail to meet your requirements?